# How to stop a dismissed view controller using a NSFetchedResultsController to listen to coredata changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management

I have a detail view containing a child view controller.
This childViewController is using a NSFetchedResultsController.

Each time I modify objects monitored by the NSFetchedResultsController, EVERY view controller that I previously opened are refreshed...

My first thought is that with ARC through swift, we don't even need to set fetchResultsDelegate = nil in the deinit() or maybe viewWillDisappear()

- Is it correct to think that?

the way I push the Swift DetailViewController (from objective C class) is:

```
DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithContactId:userId];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

the way I dismiss it (done in Obj-C super class of DetailViewController):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:@YES];
```

Comment: If you expect the view controllers to be `dealloc`'d, you should find out why they aren't.  Probably a retain cycle.

Comment: Is there an easy way to detect retain cycles? Maybe with instruments?

Comment: You were right Avi. I finally used instrument Allocation profiler in order to detect my retain cycles. I also googled "how to debug retain cycle" and found a lot of interesting pages on the topic. You can answer the question, I ll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure there are no retain cycles holding on to the dismissed view controllers.